# Marklogic cts:document-query

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Recently, I have to use MarkLogic and there are some things I don't understand.

I don't want you to clarify all my concerns regarding MarkLogic just one :)

There is an XQuery and I don't understand what it does.

```
let $pap := cts:uris(
   (), (),
   cts:and-query((
      cts:collection-query("/pageType/collection1"),
   ))
)

let $collection := ("/pageType/Attachment")
return
xdmp:estimate(
   cts:search(
      fn:doc(),
      cts:and-query((
         cts:collection-query(($collection)),
         cts:document-query($pap)
      ))
   )
)
```

I have huge problems to understand what the document-query function does.

Can somebody enlighten me, please? I am a beginner in MarkLogic who worked with relational databases before.

Thanks,

V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I neglected to answer your first question. `cts:document-query()` is documented here:

https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:document-query

In this case it is acting as a filter for the return of `cts:search` to include only documents found by the previous query `cts:uris()`

Comment: Good morning Daldei, thank you for your help! I came from relational database world and I cannot find any join in the expression above (like product.id = sale.product_id). Probably I don't need any link like this but I don't understand how the relevant pages in the two collections can 'find' each other. Thanks again, V.

Answer (score 3):

Dont feel bad for not understanding this.  Its a bit obtuse. And inefficient.

If I am reading this right what its really doing is counting the number of documents that belong to both collections "/pageType/Attachement"  and "/pageType/collection1"

I believe (offhand not tested) this could be vastly simplified by doing

xdmp:estimate(
   cts:search(
      fn:doc(),
      cts:and-query((
         cts:collection-query("/pageType/collection1"),
         cts:collection-query("/pageType/Attachment")
      ))
   )
)

Comment: There are circumstances where you might use a query like this to implement a join. Possibly this started out that way.